# How can I answer a call using the HOME button in CyanogenMod 9?

Tags: cyanogenmod, samsung-galaxy-s-2, calls

Just flashed CyanogenMod 9 RC2 on my Galaxy S2.

While I appreciate the enhanced customization and loads of options as well as the removal of some bundled Samsung bloatware apps, I do miss certain functionality - the ability to answer a call by pressing the physical HOME button.

Is there any way this functionality can be added via some setting that I've missed or via some 3rd party app?

Answer (score -1):

Go to `Settings > Accessibility > Answer calls with home button`.

Comment: Are you certain this was available in CM9. I know it was a feature in CM10.